# Show lines of a file where an argument is found

Tags: python, file, grep, glob

I want to make a simple script where the user enters an argument and all the lines where the argument exists appear on the screen.
This script will be used to make the search in one of my log files (which is very long and constantly updated) easier.
I had thought of using grep for this, then I finally got the idea to change to glob which is better since we can work with several arguments.

But the code doesn't seem to work. When I try anything, nothing is displayed. I am a beginner in python and I can't see what exactly is wrong with my code.

In case the code works, it should show all lines in the log file where the given argument is present. But this is not the case.

```
import re
import sys
import glob
import os

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Syntaxe: %s <UserID or IP Address>" % sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1])
    sys.exit(1)

file = os.path.join("/applis/tacacs/log/tacacs.log")

for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    for file in glob.iglob(arg):
        for line in open(file, 'r'):
            if re.search(sys.argv[1], line):
                print line,
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'the code doesn't work"  What errors do you get?  Which python version do you use?  ```print line,``` isn't valid Python3 syntax, btw.

Comment: @ewong There are no error. When I start the script with an argument. Just nothing happens. On the other hand, if I put no argument or two. I do get the message "Syntax: scriptacacs.py <UserID or IP Address>"

For now I'm just trying to see if the code works with one argument.

I use Python 2.7.12

Comment: you are defining file as `os.path.join.(..` and then using it a local variable `for file in glob.iglob(arg)` is there a conflict?

Comment: welcome. you might want to check out the argparse library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html it is build for your use case

Comment: @Kendle I don't have any conflict errors but maybe the problem is coming from that. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Change the first one to `fileName` ?

Comment: @Kendle You mean like this: "filename = os.path.join("/applis/tacacs/log/tacacs.log")"? 

I just did it and still nothing. Is it the "print line" that causes the problem and does not display anything maybe?